# Use the drop down list to divide my animals into categories

Tags: select, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am a programmer in aspnetcore mvc technology,
I have animals in the database that belong to categories,
I want to use the drop down list in select to sort them by categories
like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXd57.png)

I tried to do this without success so I will post what I tried to do and would love to help.

My Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
    {
        var petShopDbContext = 
            _context.Animals.Include(a => a.Category).Where(c=> c.Category.CategoryId == id);
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name");
        return View(await petShopDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

select in view:

```
<td><select asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId" onchange="location.href=this.value"></select></td>
```

View:
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication55.Models.Animal>

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhotoUrl)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.Name)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnimalId)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhotoUrl)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnimalId)
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: Hi @Yosef Abada, did you want to select all the animals and order them by CategoryId? Your code seems to be select the specific animal with specific CategoryId.

Comment: @Rena I want to sort my animals by categories

Comment: Hi @Yosef Abada, you need change your code to `var petShopDbContext = 
            _context.Animals.Include(a => a.Category).OrderBy(c=> c.Category.CategoryId);`.

Comment: @Rena and what about the select he knew to display them by categories?

Comment: @Rena I meant that I use the select command and select by category and that I select it shows me only the animals in the appropriate category

Comment: `I select it shows me only the animals in the appropriate category` I am confused. If you select the animals with appropriate category. It is no need sort by category, it has been displayed the data which are all with the same category now.

Comment: @Rena 
Yes this is what I want to do I have a select button that contains all the categories and once I select a category then it shows me all the animals that are in it
Do you understand?

Comment: But..What you did now should be work... The linq is correct for your requirement...

Comment: I tried to use what you wrote down but it still shows me all the animals in different categories except I want to use select to do that @Rena

Comment: No. I mean your code.... Your code is correctly select the animals with specific category.... What I do is to sort by category...

Comment: @Rena But when I press the select button it does not sort them for me maybe my select is not good

Comment: Hi @Yosef Abada, I will show you my sample. Maybe you still contains other thing do not share with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo you could check:

Model:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        //Category = new Category();
    }
    [Key]
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Portrait")]
    public string? PhotoUrl { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category? Category { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

View(**Index.cshtml**):

```
@model IEnumerable<Animal>               //I change the href here...
<select asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId" onchange="location.href='/Home/Index/'+this.value"></select>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhotoUrl)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.Name)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnimalId)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhotoUrl)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnimalId)
        </td>

    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller:

I modify your code :`ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryId",  "Name",id);` which is used to **maintain the selected value**. This will not influence your result.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProj6_0Context _context;
    
    public HomeController(MvcProj6_0Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
    {
        var petShopDbContext =
            _context.Animal.Include(a => a.Category).Where(c => c.Category.CategoryId == id);
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryId",  "Name",id);
        return View(await petShopDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }

}
```

Result:

When you firstly render the Index view, the id is `0` and the where clause cannot find any record in database with `id=0`. Only when you select the dropdown and pass the specific id, it will render the corresponding record.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help thank you very much works for me !!! I forgot to add some things to make it work for me lol @Rena I made his default id start from 1 to see at least something displayed